# How to divide the string depending on length in seqeunce in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, slice

```
>>>'mymedicinesarerighthere'
```

You need to break this word down in the following way:

```
>>>['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```

Comment: What have you tried.

Comment: I tried to perform string slicing. It didnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution:

```
tmpStr = "mymedicinesarerighthere"

splitList = []

ind = 1
while True:
    if len(tmpStr) > ind:
        splitList.append(tmpStr[0:ind])
        tmpStr = tmpStr[ind:]
        ind += 1
    else:
        splitList.append(tmpStr)
        break

print(splitList)

>>> ['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's python generator version.

```
def gen(a):
    start=0
    step=1
    while a[start:start+step]:
        yield a[start:start+step]
        start+=step
        step+=1

list(gen('mymedicinesarerighthere'))
# ['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```

---

Here's another approach.

You can observe that the start indices of each slice are *0,1,3,6,10...* their difference between *n<sup>th</sup>* and *n-1th* is in AP *1,2,3,4,5...*.

To get the number of partitions you have to solve this equation.

```
=>(n*(n+1))/2=len(string)
=>n^2+n-2*len(string)=0
```

Take ceil value of the `n` using `math.ceil(n)` will give us the number of partitions here it's 7 when the length of the string is 23.

```
import math
def start(n):
    return n*(n+1)//2
def findRoots(c):
    a=b=1
    d = b * b - 4 * a * c 
    sqrt_val = math.sqrt(abs(d))
    return math.ceil((-b + sqrt_val)/(2 * a))
out=[s[start(i-1):start(i-1)+i] for i in range(1,findRoots(-2*len(s))+1)]
# ['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly clean solution using some `itertools`:

```
from itertools import count, islice

def chunks(s):
    i = iter(s)
    for n in count(1):
        chunk = ''.join(islice(i, n))
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk

>>> list(chunks("mymedicinesarerighthere"))
['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```

Comment: I tried writing your itertools version in pure python approach. It was fun. Nice answer though +1. I knew the slices were in AP(arithmetic progression) i.e *0,1,3,6,10,15...* after I saw your answer I was able to do it. It would be great if you look at my code and give feedback. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
txt = "mymedicinesarerighthere"

i = 0
k = 1
myList = []
while i+k < len(txt):
  myList.append(txt[i:i+k])
  i += k
  k += 1
myList.append(txt[i: len(txt)])
print(myList)
```

### Output

```
['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```

Comment: @ArshiaMd glad it worked for you. Don't forget to mark it as the right answer and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
s='mymedicinesarerighthere'
res=[]
i,x=0,1
while (i+x)<len(s):
    res.append(s[i:x+i])
    i=i+x
    x=x+1
res.append(s[i:len(s)])
print(res)
```

output:

```
['m', 'ym', 'edi', 'cine', 'sarer', 'ighthe', 're']
```